how to create embedding for 4bit quantized llama3 model using huggingface and langchain
I am trying to do a rag using longchain and huggingface,
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

model_name = "unsloth/llama-3-8b-Instruct-bnb-4bit"
model_kwargs = {'device': device}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': False}
hf = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_name,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)
...
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=splits, embedding=hf)

However, I receive an error ValueError: Supplied state dict for layers.0.mlp.down_proj.weight does not contain bitsandbytes__* and possibly other quantized_stats components while creating the hf.
how should I correct? Thank you

hi did you find a solution? I have a similar issue
